# LaTeX3: problem with .generate_coices:n after l3kernel update

Tags: latex3, key-value

I'd like to report an issue I encountered with the `l3keys` sub-package of `l3kernel` (Hope it is ok to be done here). The test code at the end produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l_keys_choice_int
```

test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{user}{
  colour .choice_code:n = {\l_keys_choice_tl},
  colour .generate_choices:n = {black,white},
  colour .default:n = {black},
}
\newcommand\cat[1][colour]{\keys_set:nn{user}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
My cat is \cat. Your cat is \cat[colour=white].
\end{document}
```

Comment: For 'out and out' bugs like this, the bug database (https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues) would be a good place to log things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow this particular variable seems to have gone missing in the code. I will of course sort that out: the fix is trivial and should be at CTAN very soon. I will also add this to the test file: this has been missed by our automated test suite.